# Working with Websites

Tags: objective-c

I would love to create a textfield and a button. When clicking on the button it should "post" the textfield input in the chatroom I am in.

`input id="chat-submit" class="input_submit" value="Post Message" type="submit"`

This is the thing I get for the `Chatbutton` or the `Post message` button from the website.

What method do I have to use or what sample codes you guys can give me to reach why I want?

Please help me. I tried different HTTPRequest things, but I don't know where to put my information of the chat button...

I want to create a kinda mobile chat of this...

Comment: Could you please just clarify what you want, from what I understand you're making an iPhone app and you want to essentially fill in a form then send it? If that's the case then you need to issue a post request. Please also give us some sample code that you have tried to work off.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to know how to create an HTTP POST request, and populate it with parameters?

Unless you use a third party library, in Cocoa you have to assemble the POST request body yourself. You could use code like this:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = ...;
    NSMutableString *ps = [NSMutableString string];

    BOOL first = YES;
    for (NSString *key in self.postParameters)
    {
        [ps appendFormat:@"%@%@=%@", (first==YES) ? @"" : @"&", key, [[self.postParameters objectForKey:key] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        first=NO;
    }

    NSData* postVariables = [ps dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString* postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", [postVariables length]];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: postVariables];
```

This code assumes that you have an NSDictionary `self.postParameters` that contains the things you want to POST.

Once you've made the `NSMutableURLRequest`, you send it off using `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: okay thanx. so for request = myURL to chat right? and where do I have to enter the id of the chat button and stuff? I had such codes like above but I didn't know where to enter the code that is required so it works..